# Make a way to navigate pages while pausing 'new question pushdown'

Tags: feature-request, pagination

I like to scan questions with the 50 items per page option turned on, but by the time I've gotten to the end, perhaps pausing to answer or comment on something, the next page often ends up being half filled with the questions from the page I just left since pages are relative to the beginning of the question list.  It would seem a lot more intuitive if I click next on a page, I should be showed the next set of items relative to where I just was, not relative to the first question.

Answer (score 3):

Why not fire up a few tabs and let them stew some seconds before checking them out?

You have four (4) tabs from the start and it wouldn't be that much of a strain to load them up so when you check out the pages they all keep their relativityessness.

Comment: because I shouldn't have to.  Besides, today's data shows that 8 hours of data could easily cover a dozen pages or more.  Ironic for a site called stack overflow that I can't get an iterator to the stack of questions, only an index offset.

Comment: Needs a 100 results setting to buffer against this pushing off the cliff.